# Yanking into a regexp isearch escapes the metacharacters

Tags: isearch

I noticed today that when I yank a string containing regexp metacharacters into an active regexp isearch, the metacharacters all get escaped.  For example, if I've killed the text `foo*` and yank that string into a search, it becomes `foo\*`.

My actual use case involved me generating a list of alternatives I wanted to search for in a temporary buffer, and then joining them together with `\|`.  Something like `foo\|bar\|...\|baz`.  In the buffer I wanted to search, I started a regexp search and pasted in that string, but it became `foo\\|bar\\|...\\|baz`.

I haven't been able to find this behavior described in the docs.  I got around it by calling `eval-expression` and providing my string to `search-forward-regexp`, but that's obviously kind of a hassle, and moreover doesn't let me repeat the search with a simple `C-s`.

The behavior I described doesn't seem correct to me, or at least not intuitive, but is it documented somewhere?  If it is correct, are there any other reasonable workarounds?

Comment: @Drew I specified "regexp (i)search" multiple times.

Comment: Another workaround (still far from ideal):  start a regular search with `C-s`, yank your pattern with `C-y` then toggle regex on with `M-r`. At this point highlighting works, but when you hit enter the search will fail. However, the pattern is now in the regex search history and if you run `C-M-s`, `C-s` now it will work.

Answer (score 1):

You have this option with [Isearch+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IsearchPlus): [`isearchp-regexp-quote-yank-flag`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IsearchPlus#isearchp-regexp-quote-yank-flag):

> **`isearchp-regexp-quote-yank-flag`** is a variable defined in [`isearch+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/isearch%2b.el).
>
> Its value is `t`
>
> Documentation:
>
> Non-`nil` means escape special chars in text yanked for a regexp isearch.
>
> You can toggle this using `` M-= ` ``  during Isearch.
>
> You can customize this variable.

Note that though this is a user option, you can toggle its value anytime during Isearch. The option value, in effect, specifies the *default* behavior.

Code is [here](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/isearch%2b.el).